# scripting canonical partner source addition

Tags: command-line, apt, text-processing, software-sources

I'd like to make sure the "partner" sources has been added within a script no matter the release of ubuntu i'm dealing with.

So far I've got :

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo sed -i 's/# deb http:\/\/archive.canonical.com\/ubuntu xenial partner/deb http:\/\/archive.canonical.com\/ubuntu xenial partner/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Since this is a file in `/etc` I added `sudo` I imagine that's mandatory.

How would I get this to work cross-release?

thank you.

Comment: I doubt `sed` likes linebreaks in the command arguments.

Comment: that was a typo . my bad the real issue is how to get this working cross-relese

Comment: This is past my skill level with sed but the command `lsb_release --codename` returns the release code name 'xenial', which may help? You'll have to echo it in there somehow I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pick the codename from `sources.list`, since it already includes it:

```
sudo sed -i 's,# \(deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu [a-z]* partner\),\1,' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I'm using `,` as the separator for `s` to avoid leaning toothpicks. Here, since the replacement text is pretty much already in the match, we can use regex groups (`\(...\)`) to use them in the replacement (`\1`).

Comment: will this also work with non ubuntu debian-based distros?

Comment: @tatsu do non-Ubuntu Debian-based distros work have the Canonical partner repo in their sources.list?

Comment: that's what i wonder. I think yes. canonical have no reason to want to prevent that plus it's incredibly reliable so other distros probably wouldn't want to miss out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty conviced

```
sudo sed -i 's/# deb http:\/\/archive.canonical.com/deb http:\/\/archive.canonical.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

will work on any release

there's only that line plus the "partners-dev" that matches in that file and "partners" is the first match.